# Google's geocoding API with a service account

Tags: google-maps, google-maps-api-3, service-accounts

I wanted to make requests to Google's geocoding API using a service account authentication/authorization instead of the regular API key. However I found no example of such implementation or any indication that it is even possible. I also didn't find anything saying it is not, therefore this question: does anyone know if it's possible and how to do it?

My last attempt ended up with this error:

`{
  "error": "invalid_scope",
  "error_description": "Empty or missing scope not allowed."
}`

which makes sense, since I could not find the [right scope](https://developers.google.com/identity/protocols/googlescopes).

Comment: As far as I know Google Maps web services don't support authentication with service accounts. The only supported methods are API keys or client ID with digital signature in Premium plan.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Geocoding API does not support access using service accounts. API key and clientid/digi signature is the only process till date

Comment: Cheers mate, I got to the same conclusion. Welcome to SO!